# Save contact to phone not opening save contact screen directly (iPhone users) using php

Tags: php, laravel, vcf-vcard

I have implemented save contact functionality using php language. which generates a vcf file.

https://app.myrepcard.com/user/606

When above link is open in iphone and on save contact button it download vcf and open up the save contact options. but right now there is no save option. you have to click on right top share button and then save to contacts and then it will show save contact option.

So is there any way to directly open that screen where you will have save option.[image: You can check the screen which appears on save contact]

Comment: does your php script adds proper mime type to response, i.e. ```text/vcard```?

Comment: Yes. uses https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard. The headers are generated by this package.

Comment: It was apples feature added in ios 12 or 13 that they have to go through the share button and then in next screen it will ask user to save to contact but it's changed back in ios 14 and they have give add button option in the same screen now.